# Read input from the webpage, parse the data submitted using python or tcl and start the script execution based on the inputs given

Tags: python-2.7, tcl

I want to take input from the webpage, parse the data submitted using python or tcl and start the script execution based on the inputs given. 
Please suggest me a solution, how it can be done. 
I am not sure whether some web server need to be started for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Surya

Comment: Of course you're gonna need web server. But that's the only thing we can say. You have to provide more information. What is the problem you're dealing with? What have you tried so far? SO is not a forum - it's a technical Q&A site and we need to know that you have a basic understanding of the topic.

Comment: @Jerry are you 100% sure that `something` can answer to HTTP POST/GET request (form submit) and this `something` is not a Web Server? It may be a dumb Web Server but still it's a Web Server.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo 

Thanks for the reply first.

I am not expecting the code. Just wanted to know the package/tool with which we get this done.

For example I have a html file wherein it has 1 textbox and submit button, after pressing submit button, I want to read the value of the textbox and start a tcl script based on the input. I tried with simple tcl_httpd, it is able to receive the request. But I am not able to process the query.

Answer (score 0):

Surya, 
you should have a look at the ncgi and htmlparse packages in tcllib to extract the information you need. 
Joachim

Comment: Am I the only one who can see that the question says about `submitted` data? It's not about parsing HTML - it's about getting data from HTML form. OP used word `parsing` by mistake I believe.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo 
Thanx...
Sorry if I my explanation lead to confusion. Actually the problem I am facing is just want to get the submitted data in array or variable, rest of the things I am able to do it. So far I did, started a simple httpd with which I am sending a default url when received a request on 8080 port. when I type localhost:8080 in the web browser I am able to see the default page. In which I have a text field and a submit button. I got stuck right here, I dont understand how to get the submitted data and from where I have to get it. Do I need to customize the httpd script?

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way to get up and going with Tcl handling HTML form submission is with venerable old CGI. (It's not the most efficient, but it lets you get going immediately without having to do a lot of work setting up a custom web server.) The Tcl community standard library, Tcllib, has a number of very useful packages to help.

To parse the submitted form, the [ncgi](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/ncgi/ncgi.html) package is highly recommended. To generate the resulting HTML response, the [html](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/html/html.html) package is quite useful, especially in conjunction with `subst`.

```
package require ncgi
package require html

proc parseQuery {} {
    ncgi::parse
    # Gets just the 'q' parameter from the form
    return [ncgi::value q]
}
proc generateAnswer {q} {
    puts [html::doctype HTML401T]
    puts [subst {
        [html::head "The answer"]
        [html::bodyTag]
        [html::h1 "The answer is..."]
        [html::if {[string match {*\?} $q]} {
            "[html::quoteFormValue $q]" Maybe...
        } else {
            I do <i>not</i> know what you are talking about!
        }]
        [html::end]
    }]
}
generateAnswer [parseQuery]
```

Mind you, I'd actually wrap things up for greater clarity so that the HTML output was separated from the parsing; it's a bit longer, but rather easier to read and maintain:

```
package require ncgi
package require html

proc parseQuery {} {
    ncgi::parse
    # Gets just the 'q' parameter from the form
    return [dict set q [ncgi::value q]]
}
# A little general template application engine
proc applyTemplate {templateFile dictionary} {
    namespace eval tmpl [list variable {*}$dictionary]
    namespace eval tmpl {namespace import ::html::*}
    set f [open $templateFile]
    set template [read $f]
    close $f
    puts [namespace eval tmpl [list ::subst $template]]
}
applyTemplate answer.tmpl [parseQuery]
```

And here's the template in `answer.tmpl`…

```
[doctype HTML401T]
[head "The answer"]
[bodyTag]
[h1 "The answer is..."]
[if {[::string match {*\?} $q]} {
    "[quoteFormValue $q]" Maybe...
} else {
    I do <i>not</i> know what you are talking about!
}]
[end]
```